# Qt pushButton and inheritance

Tags: c++, qt

I ran into a problem with `QPushButton`. I have got three different classes(windows) , there are different pushbuttons,which I created in every class(window),  they have red colors(that means I added special methods to set a color for these very pushbuttons in every class).

Now I have to create  `QRadioButtons` with chosing a color of pushbuttons on Main Window. But I can't do that in general, I only can do for main windwow pushbuttons, not for 2d and 3d window.

My main idea of sloving this problem is inheritance, so I need to create an own abstract class `PushButton`,which is included some special attributes(size ,color and so on). Then I need to  inheritance from the main class `QPushButton`.

Trithfully, it is easy to say but it's difficult to do. Can you help with realization ,please? Know that it isn't a tutorial thing. But if you can, thanks!

My example, so I have a main window:

```
    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();
        QLabel *label_pic;

        QRadioButton *yellow;
        QRadioButton *black;
        QRadioButton *blue;

        QRadioButton *button_red;
        QRadioButton *button_green;
        QRadioButton *button_yellow;

    private slots:
      [......]

        void button_yellow_clicked();
        void button_green_clicked();
        void button_red_clicked();

        [......]
    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    };
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   [.....created some buttons....]
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    yellow=new QRadioButton(this);
    yellow->setText("Yellow");
    yellow->setGeometry(QRect(120,270, 100, 20));

    button_red=new QRadioButton(this);
    button_red->setText("Red");
    button_red->setGeometry(QRect(230,300, 100, 20));  
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    connect(button_yellow,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(button_yellow_clicked()));

}

void MainWindow::button_yellow_clicked()
{
    ui->pushButton_2->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(2, 120, 0); color: rgb(4, 208, 63)");

}
```

So , them have another class with another button, but I would like to change by one click , by one `QRadiButton` in Main Button.

Comment: You shouldn't extend push buttons just to change their colors. You can style those.

Comment: use quotes for code style formatting and use bold font for... well for nothing. I allowed myself to fix that for you

Comment: @dtech yes, I know that, but imagine I have 5-6 pushbuttons in every window under one color , now I want to change their color. I'd like to chage "By one click",you get me. Otherwise, I would like to creat a special class for this.

Comment: still you do not need different classes to make them in different colours. Thats like saying "I need to buy 5 cars of 5 different brands to be able to paint them in 5 different colours" - No you dont, just take 5 times the same car and paint them in different colours

Comment: @tobi303 so how should I turn  to another objects of  `QPushButtons` from another classes in `Main Window`?

Comment: first edit question remove everything about inheritance and simply explain what kind of look you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use style sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html). They are easy to use and do exactly what you want.

`setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: yellow }");` will change the color of all pushbuttons in the MainWindow to yellow.

so in your code

```
void MainWindow::button_yellow_clicked()
{
    ui->pushButton_2->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: yellow }");    
}
```

if you want this behaviour for **all** QPushButtons in your application, not just the QPushButtons in MainWindow:

`qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: yellow }");`

Answer (score 0):

If you what to tweak colors of window elements the best and simplest approach is to use [`QPalette`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html).
[image: qt palette explained]
If you are using Qt Designer (design your main windows with mouse), you can edit this by manse. Just select MainWindow object and in property editor find "palette" and double click it (some dialog will lead you by hand).

If you want to do this application wide you can set this palette on QApplication object. Most probably this is to hard for you (for now).

---

Alternative approach is to [use style sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html). It is more powerful and more complex (especially for beginners).

Comment: @MarekR please look at example in a question

Comment: @nikitaxgusev I can see you are trying to use a style sheet, but you are doing that wrong. Do not set style sheet on individual widgets. Set it on QApplication (so they will impact all widows and widgets) or on MainWindow.

Comment: @MakerR Please, give me an example, please

Comment: Look on @WiBu answer, he just extend second part of my answer.